# p:inputText does not remember values(autofill does not work)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

How to make p:inputText remember values? I have  autocomplete="on" in there but it doesnot work.

Please find the code below:

```
<p:inputText id="username_email" value="#{BsnsSgnupLgnBen.userName}" required="true" size="25" autocomplete="on" >
  <f:validateLength minimum="0" maximum="50" />
</p:inputText>
```

Any clue?

Comment: primefaces autocomplete is not equivalent to browser's auto complete.

Answer (score 3):

Browser-builtin autocomplete/autofill is only triggered during synchronous page load. So, if you're loading your forms by ajax, then autocomplete/autofill is not triggered. Apparently that's what happening here. The solution is obvious: you need to load your forms on which you need autocomplete/autofill synchronously. E.g. by `<h:link>`, `<h|p:button>`, etc or a navigation with `faces-redirect=true`.

As the particular input field seems to be part of a login form, I just want to add for sake of completeness, another thing to take into account is that usernames/passwords of login forms (a form is considered a login form when it has at least one `<input type="password">` field) are not remembered for autocomplete/autofill when the login itself is submitted by ajax. You should perform the actual login synchronously. You can use `<p:commandButton ajax="false">` for this.

Please do note that the concrete problem has completely nothing to do with JSF. It's in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. You'd have had exactly the same problem when using a different server side language generating the very same HTML output and even when using plain vanilla HTML.

Answer (score -4):

I think you should use the autoComplete component from Primefaces http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autocompleteHome.jsf

Comment: I think OP wants browser  to remember already entered values by users in  input text. And not a list loaded from server

Comment: @Abhishek then, you should configure your browser to achieve it

Comment: @Abhishek My answer was according to your code. Primefaces doesn't work like browser's autocomplete (as was mentioned)

Comment: The `<p:autocomplete>` component has completely nothing to do with browser-builtin autocomplete/autofill which the OP is concretely asking about. The `<p:autocomplete>` only suggests server-definied values in flavor of a dropdownlist on a regular input field. What the OP is asking is that the webbrowser should open the page with the form *already* filled out with the last entered/submitted values.